# Finding net torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

There are two torques $T_1$ and $T_2$ which are acting at two different points on a body. The directions of $T_1$ and $T_2$ are along the z-axis, assuming that the motion of the body is confined to the x-y plane. Also, it is given that the net force acting on the system is zero.

Is the net torque acting on the system along the z-axis equal to $T_1 + T_2$?

Answer (score 1):

If the net force acting on the system is zero, then the only way for there to be a net torque is if the two torques are due to two equal but opposite forces that are parallel to each other, and acting at different points. See the diagram below. In statics this is called a couple. A couple produces pure rotation without translation. Each force $F$ in the diagram creates a counter clockwise torque equal to $\frac{Fd}{2}$ for a total torque of $Fd$. Since the forces themselves are equal and opposite, there is no net force causing the center of the mass to accelerate in any direction.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though torque is a vector quantity, they are both along the same direction in this situation. Hence, you can add the two torques $T_1$ and $T_2$ to obtain the net torque on the body.

Comment: Is it valid even if `T1` and `T2` are about different point ???

Comment: You arent getting it. The force applied is about two different different points. The torques are about the same point

Comment: If I am getting it right, you mean the forces (cause of the torques) are acting at different points and the direction of the torques (along z-axis) are the same.

Comment: Yes, the torque is always along the centre of mass of the body in direction ${F\times l}$

Comment: Can't we exploit the net-zero force condition to find the net torque? As, when the net force on the system is zero then the net torque about any point is independent of the reference point.

Comment: I didnt get what you are trying to say. The question probably said that net force is zero to convey that none of the force applied went into accelerating the body. All of the force was used to increase the torque.

Comment: @TSSingh I think you will find my post answers your questions.